# How is it possible to reference a method with one argument to a target with two in Lambda here?

Tags: java, lambda

In Lambda expressions I'm studying the following example.
But I don't understand the logic of the code here.

How or where the function sameTemp is executed here. Because I pass it as a method reference but then I call `f.func(vals[i], v)` even though sameTemp accepts 1 argument.

```
package lambda;

//A functional interface that takes two reference arguments 
//and returns a boolean result. 
interface MyFunc5<T> {
    boolean func(T v1, T v2);
}

class HighTemp {

    private int hTemp;

    HighTemp(int ht) {
        hTemp = ht;
    }

    boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
        return hTemp == ht2.hTemp;
    }

    boolean lessThanTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
        return hTemp < ht2.hTemp;
    }

}

public class InstanceMethWithObjectRefDemo {

    static <T> int counter(T[] vals, MyFunc5<T> f, T v) {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
            if (f.func(vals[i], v))
                count++;

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count;

        // Create an array of HighTemp objects.
        HighTemp[] weekDayHighs = { new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(82), new HighTemp(89)};
        //Why there is no error referencing sameTemp to the place of MyFunc5<T> f because MyFunc5<T> f
        //has 2 args while sameTemp has 1
        count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::sameTemp, new HighTemp(89));
        System.out.println(count + " days had a high of 89");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a method reference in the form `Type::instanceMethod` (not to be confused with `instance::instanceMethod`), the resulting lambda implicitly expects an instance as its first argument and invokes the method on that instance with the remaining arguments. So `HighTemp::sameTemp` is the equivalent of `(HighTemp ht1, HighTemp ht2) -> ht1.sameTemp(ht2)`, which is the same functional signature as `MyFunc5.func()` when `T` is `HighTemp`.

In other words, when you call `f.func(vals[i], v)`, it gets translated to `vals[i].sameTemp(v)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in this case is `vals[i]` itself. So basically

```
f.func(vals[i], v)
```

with `HighTemp::sameTemp` as `f` becomes

```
vals[i].sameTemp(v)
```